# program(array to struct)warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, arrays, struct, printf

I am to use a program wherein a data from `array` would be passed to the `struct`. But I always get a warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast. How do I fix it?

Code:

```
struct player_t = 
      {
       char player_name;
       char player_number;
      };

char name[], number[];
      (some code to take the input)

int x=0;

struct player_t info[] = 
    {
        info[x].player_name = name
            info[x].player_number = number
    };


    printf("%s\n%s", info[x].player_name, info[x].player_number);
```

Comment: I think it wants a type cast (like int(var)), probably in your print statement.

Comment: @IsaiahTaylor: Nope. First, that's not the right syntax for a cast in C. Second, a cast is not the solution to the problem.

Comment: Please post actual code, copy-and-pasted from something that compiles. (There is no `=` in a `struct` definition; you would have gotten a syntax error message if you had actually compiled that.) If the problem is that you can't get it to compile, post the actual code along with the exact error message, indicating clearly which line in your source code the message refers to.

Answer (score 2):

`player_name` is declared as `char`, which is a (fairly small) integer. You assign that from `name` which is a `char[]`, i.e. an array of (fairly small) integers. When you use an array name like that, it "decays" into a pointer to the first element of the array.

So:

```
info[x].player_name = name;
```

is trying to assign a pointer to an integer, and the compiler feels obliged to warn you that it's probably not what you wanted to do. And it's not. But I cannot figure out what you are trying to do, so I can't offer you any better advice than the compiler.

Comment: Should I make it info[x].player_name = (char)name; ?

Comment: @toshi: As I said, I don't really know what you're trying to do. But that is almost certainly not what you want to do, unless you believe that player_name's are all single characters. (And in that case, you'd need to print them as single characters, not as strings.) You *probably* want to *copy* the string or some such. For what its worth, C++ strings (that is, std::string) is a lot more intuitive, and also a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
struct player_t = 
  {
   char player_name;
   char player_number;
  };
```

Well, no, actually you don't.  There's no `=` in the syntax of a `struct` definition, and you didn't mention a syntax error message. You probably have something more like this:

```
struct player_t
{
    char player_name;
    char player_number;
};
```

Your structure contains just two `char` members, which are not enough to hold a name or number (unless the name is limited to a single letter, and the number either to a single digit or to a very small value, depending on how you store it). So that's the root of your problem.

Assuming you want both the name and the number to be stored as strings, you can make both members *arrays* of `char`, for example:

```
#define MAX_LEN 50
struct player_t
{
    char player_name[50];
    char player_number[50];
};
```

Then you'll need to use the `strcpy()` function to copy a string value into `player_name` and `player_number` -- or you can initialize them with string literals, but that doesn't let you determine the name and number during program execution. You'll also have to be careful not to try to store strings longer than `player_name` and `player_number` can hold. For a first attempt, you can *temporarily* ignore that issue until you get the program working; eventually you'll want to add error handling code, which includes deciding what to do if there is an error.

Or you can make them pointers:

```
struct player_t
{
    char *player_name;
    char *player_number;
};
```

This lets you do things like:

```
players[3].player_name = "Fred";
```

But you'll have to allocate the name and number for each player individually; you can't just have the `player_name` members for all your players point to the same object. For example:

```
char name[30] = "Fred";
players[3].player_name = name;
```

Modifying `name` will also modify the string pointed to by `players[3].player_name`.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to print player_t fields as character arrays, but actually they are single characters. Modify your player_t structure like this:

```
struct player_t = 
{
  char* player_name;
  char* player_number;
};
```

Comment: If he does this, all his players will have the same name and number, because the loop will just copy the address of `name` and `number` into each of them.